# « Résumer » : Quelles notions sémantiques sous-jacentes rapprochent les sens de « reprendre » et « synthétiser » ?

Tags: étymologie, latin

> [ [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9sumer#.C3.89tymologie) :] Du latin [*resumere*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/resumo#la) (« reprendre »), passé, en latin scolastique, au sens de « reprendre sommairement ».
>
> [ [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=resume&allowed_in_frame=0) :] 
>       also résumé, 1804, "a summary," from French *résumé*, noun use of past participle of Middle French *resumer* "to sum up," from Latin *resumere* (see [resume](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=resume&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.)).

À titre du verbe « resumer » , comment a évolué le sens de « reprendre » (qui dérive du latin *resumere*)  et « reprendre sommairement » pour signifier « synthétiser » ?
Quelles notions sémantiques sous-jacents les rapprochent ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le verbe *résumer* vient du latin *resumo*, composé du préfixe *re-* indiquant une répétition et de *[sumo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sumo#Latin)* qui a beaucoup de sens dont *prendre*. Le verbe latin *[resumo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/resumo#Latin)* a conservé plusieurs de ces sens dont celui de dire quelque chose à nouveau. En français moderne, un des sens de *reprendre* est d'ailleurs de répéter un argument, bien que *prendre* n'ait pas de sens correspondant.

En [moyen français](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/r%C3%A9sumer) (15<sup>e</sup> siècle), *resumer* signifiait répéter, reprendre des propos, et en particulier les reprendre sous une forme plus brève. Le *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*, dès sa [première éditition](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50398c/f405.image) (fin du 17<sup>e</sup> siècle) ne liste plus que le sens « Recueillir, reprendre en peu de paroles ». Il mentionne que le mot est surtout utilisé dans le « dogmatique », c'est-à-dire dans des discussions sur la religion.

Il y a donc eu un glissement de sens de « répéter un argument » à « répéter un argument de façon abrégée », et c'est l'aspect « abréger » qui est prépondérant en français moderne.

Answer (score 0):

La question propose une analyse de *résumer* (reprendre en plus court<sup>1</sup>) à partir de deux points deux vue :

> - *Reprendre* : prendre à nouveau ce qu'on a cessé d'avoir ou d'utiliser
> - *Synthétiser* : associer, combiner, réunir

De fait *faire un résumé* n'implique pas de *faire une synthèse*, beaucoup de média  :

- font faire le résumé des discours politiques par des journalistes qui en extraient les phrases clefs
- font faire des analyses politiques par des correspondants qualifiés, souvent des spécialistes et experts reconnus.

Dans la vie courante, les responsables demandent à leurs subordonnés de faire  “un résumé de la situation” qui souvent sont des “synthèses des contraintes à maîtriser”.

> - *Résumer* a pour synonyme : *abréger, condenser*
> - *Se résumer* a pour synonyme : *se réduire, se limiter*

Le contraire étant *développer*.

---

<sup>*Toutes le références sont extraites du petit Robert*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

ce qui les rapproche, c'est "sommairement": on redonne le contexte, en plus bref.

A part ça je ne sache pas qu'en Français on retrouver le sens "reprendre" identique à l'anglais: il y a aura toujours la connotation qu'on récapitule pour se remettre dans le contexte, avant de continuer.